# g:select tag in grails does not store key of list element in target field

Tags: grails, gsp

I have the following codeline in my grails view

```
<g:select id="partner" name="partner.id" from="${org.strotmann.partner.Partner.partners}" optionKey="id" value="${auftragInstance?.kundenNr}" class="many-to-one" noSelection="['null': '']"/>
```

I expect it to show me the list specified in the from clause as a select box (that works fine)

After selecting an Item from the box I expect that it stores the id of that Item in the field specified in the value clause ( that does not work, always null)

I'm somewhat confused, because the followin codeLine does exactly what I expect:

```
<g:select id="partner" name="partner.id" from="${org.strotmann.partner.Partner.partners}" optionKey="id" value="${arbeitsgangInstance?.kundenNr}" class="many-to-one" noSelection="['null': '']"/>
```

Can anybody tell me where I can find a difference or how to recode my  ?

peter

let me reformulate my question:

I have a list

```
org.strotmann.partner.Partner.partners
```

It contains partners with just the attribute name and of course the id.

I want the names in a selectList and want the id of a partner stored in

```
auftragInstance.kundenNr
```

feel free to code a working g:select

peter

Comment: Look at the generated HTML to see if the proper value is set

Comment: how can I see the generated HTML ?

Comment: ok found the generated HTML, it's just a browser function, now I try to get some useful infirmation from it

Comment: I just compared the generated html of my 2 selects, they are exactly the same one is working fine one does not, strange

Answer (score 2):

The value attribute is used to provide the initial selection. The name attribute will contain the selected value when the form is submitted. In a controller you can get it like this:

```
def partner = params.partner
```

See:
[select tag in grails documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html)

Comment: I know where to find the documentation of the select tag, thank you anyway. But I do not understand that documentation. Especially I find no answer for a simple question: where can I code the target field of the selected key? is it name, key, value, id, optionKey, optionValue or anything else ?

Comment: the name of the target field is in name. So if you say in your select tag name="partner" it will be available in params.partner. If you say name="foo", it will be available in params.foo.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to comment from masc I found that there was just missing the following code snippet in save and update method of AuftragController:

```
if (params.partner.id == 'null')
        salesOrderInstance.kundenNr = 0
    else
        salesOrderInstance.kundenNr = params.partner.id.toLong()
```

That code block was allready contained in ArbeitsgangController, and therefore the second html-line in my question was working fine.

the following select (with id and value clauses omitted) will also do:

```
<g:select name="partner.id" from="${org.strotmann.partner.Partner.partners}" optionKey="id" class="many-to-one" noSelection="['null': '']"/>
```

sorry the value entry

```
value="${auftragInstance?.kundenNr}"
```

must not be removed, it is important for update.